# How to add a column with an index to an apache arrow dataset in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, apache-arrow

I'm trying to add an index to a dataset which is too large to fit in RAM. The tidyverse way of adding an index would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = mtcars
df |>
  mutate(row_id = 1:nrow(cyl)) # any column name in the df
```

Dplyr backend for Arrow doesn't allow for this operation. How else can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to use `nrow(column name)`? `mutate(row_id = row_number())` or `mutate(row_id = 1:n())` will also works.

Comment: It won't work until I call collect(). I want to avoid reading the data to memory since it's too big. Your example won't work:
```
> dat |>
+   mutate(index = row_number())
Error: Expression row_number() not supported in Arrow
Call collect() first to pull data into R.
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need an index?  I don't think this is possible, as there are no bindings for `row_number()` at the moment, but there may be an alternative way to achieve the thing you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use an index as a unique ID for each row. I have around 55 CSV files which are over 80 GB in total size, and I want a unique ID across all of those 55 files without reading them all into memory.

Comment: Can't you just do it one file at a time? Also why are you keeping them as csv instead of parquet?

Comment: Because I received these files as csv... Happy to see a reproducible example of your suggested solution!

Comment: David I had a read through the documentation of `arrow`, the cheatsheet, and the cookbook. All of them have the same direction/point - you use the `dplyr`-like functions, then always end with `collect()`- to quote the docs, "No actual computations are performed until collect() (or the related compute() function) is called"

Comment: So the two possibilities which may provide options are compute() - "compute() stores results in a remote temporary table" https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/compute.html . It seems like it maybe doesn't load all the data in, maaybe. And the other option is to break your data into further chunks, and work on those